# FileVault 2 encrypted disks with my home directory on a different drive

Tags: filevault, keychain

I have multiple volumes on my mac and I just enabled encryption on the other drives. My home folder is stored on one of those drives. Now I can't login because it can't see my home directory, but if I login with my admin account it unlocks the drives and then I can login.

How do I add those passwords to my login keychain, so they can find my home directory?

I could decrypt my home directory, but that kind of defeats the purpose of having it encrypted. And my home directory is too big to fit on my boot disk.

Comment: Old issue I know, but for anyone else interested I just wanted to say; why would you want it to unlock automatically without a password being entered? Personally I prefer the way this "bug" operates, as it means that my admin account (the only one in my case) must sign in before the other users can be accessed, so even if those users have relatively weak passwords, it's more secure.

Answer (score 1):

When logged in as your admin user, you can use Keychain Access.app and just move (or copy) the keychain item containing the password for the encrypted volume to the System keychain.  This makes the password available at boot time. I've got a similar setup, and it worked like this for me.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. It seems like it should though... Now that it's in the system keychain I'm going to try copying it to my account's login keychain also.

Comment: Putting it in your user account's keychain won't help because that's stored in your home folder, and hence isn't available until *after* the volume is decrypted.

Comment: "… it didn't work …" – in what way did it not work? Did, for example, a process write under the mount point before the logical volume was automatically unlocked?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've added your non-admin account to the list of users permitted to unlock the drive. This is accomplished in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Filevault.

http://one.utsa.edu/sites/oit/OITConnect/mac/MacKB/Pages/Adding%20Login%20Users%20to%20FileVault.aspx

Comment: It wasn't a non-admin account.  It was an admin account that existed exclusively on an encrypted drive.

Comment: You said, "if I login with my admin account it unlocks the drives and then I can login" so I based my answer on that.

Comment: Oh, sorry I did.  The problem also existed for admin accounts that were on the second disk.