# How to set up ZEVO / ZFS on an internal disk while maintaining full disk encryption?

Tags: filevault, encryption, zfs, macos

It seems that it's currently impossible to have the entire boot drive converted to ZFS.

How would one go about converting a single disk HFS+ Filevault 2 setup into a setup which has full encryption and most of the advantages of ZFS?

I imagine that there will have to remain a boot partition which is HFS+ and all user data would have to somehow live on an encrypted ZFS partition that will get auto-mounted and perhaps symlinked to /Users ...

I'm on 10.8.3 and with CE Zevo (1.1)

Comment: Are you referring to something like this? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52919/how-can-zfs-be-used-with-encryption-on-os-x Look at the answer by Graham Perrin.

Comment: Paging [Graham Perrin](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/8546/graham-perrin). . . . GJ - You'll want to explicitly list a version of OS X and ZEVO/ZFS if you have any constraints you wish to have in force. You clearly can do this on Lion following the link above.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on 10.8.3 and CE Zevo, so would appreciate and up to date answer as well as a bit more newbie-friendly instructions than those found in Graham's previous answer.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the alert!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer … two Core Storage logical volumes, both encrypted:

- one LV, HFS Plus
- the other LV, give to ZEVO.

You'll need ZEVO Community Edition 1.1.1 (1.1 is outdated).

In the answer to the linked question there's a note about Mountain Lion; OS X 10.8.5 makes things a little more difficult.

Comment: Thanks, but I am mostly wondering about how to elegantly set up the Users to live on a different volume and auto-mount etc. Perhaps this isn't a zevo/zfs-specific question but is nevertheless essential in this context due to zevo's inability to work for boot partitions.