# MacZfs with encryption on os-x

Tags: disk-utility, encryption, zfs

I have followed [these steps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52919/how-can-zfs-be-used-with-encryption-on-os-x) for setting up zfs (maczfs 74.3.0, OSX 10.8.3) with encryption. Everything works fine, till I restart the computer.

After the restart, diskutil informs me that the file system is invalid and refuse to mount my ZFS pool disk:

```
 **Mount failed**    
 The disk “Workspace” could not be mounted. 
 Try running First Aid on the  disk and then retry mounting.
```

When I run the Verify Disc, I get an error:

```
...
The volume <UUID OF MY ZFS LOGICAL VOLUME> appears to be OK.
Checking file systemChecking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
Invalid B-tree node size
The volume   could not be verified completely.
Error: This disk needs to be repaired. Click Repair Disk.
```

The cause of the error is that the Logical Volume is ZFS.

How can I mount my ZFS partition? I wonder whether it is not an issue with maczfs or the way I created my pool (*zpool create /dev/disk2*).